# gnuplot - plot both from a data file and a gnuplot function in a single image

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have the following snippet:

```
set grid

set xlabel "Entropy"
set ylabel "Amortized work"
set xrange [-0.05:1.05]

set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#516db0' linetype 2 linewidth 5

f(x) = -1.3973 * x ** 2 + 1.3947 * x + 0.5796
F = '$-1.3973 x^2 + 1.3947 x + 0.5796$'

set terminal cairolatex pdf input size 700,700 color colortext
set key opaque box lc "black" linewidth 3

plot 'RatioVerboseData.dat', f(x) 

set output
```

The data file `RatioVerboseData.dat` looks like this:

```
0.93070 0.290710
0.94060 0.281450
0.95050 0.254771
0.96040 0.241656
```

When I run the script with the gnuplot, it outputs:

```
plot 'RatioVerboseData.dat', f(x)
                              ^
cairolatex terminal cannot write to standard output
"EntropyVerboseData.plt", line 15: util.c: No error
```

I use gnuplot 4.6.7 and MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.10 (MiKTeX 22.7)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an output file.  Otherwise gnuplot tries to write back to the input terminal (stdout).  That makes sense for some terminal types, e.g. the "dumb" terminal, and is not revelant for terminal type with their own display window, e.b. "qt", "wxt".  But it cannot work for terminal types that need to create multiple output streams and then combine them to produce the final document, which covers most (all?) of the LaTeX terminal types.

Add a line:

```
set output "RatioVerboseData.tex"
```

Comment: Adding the line led me to another difficulty: gnuplot stucks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a 7.5 year old gnuplot version? Current version is 5.4.

I can reproduce your observation (on Win10 with gnuplot 4.6.7) that gnuplot gets stuck.
I couldn't find a hint in `help cairolatex`, but I guess if you don't add units to the size it will be interpreted as inches. But this does not yet explain why gnuplot freezes when you want to create a `700in x 700in` large graph.

Anyway, if you add units, I guess at least `in` and `cm` are accepted *and* if you add the output file as @Ethan already suggested then it should work.

```
...
set terminal cairolatex pdf input size 7cm,7cm color colortext
set output "RatioVerboseData.tex"
...
```

Comment: I had issues with 5.4.4 as well.

Comment: @coderodde You had or you are still having problems with `7cm,7cm`? Question answered, problem solved?